# $stdout.gets blocks when it should return output, why?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, pipe

I have such server schema:

```
sleep 5
puts 'Server started'
loop { }
```

When I run it in irb:

arr = Open3.popen3('ruby server.rb')
arr[1].gets

the gets blocks, and even I know it should return 'Server started' it does not.
When I interrupt it and call `arr[1].gets` again, it returns 'Server started' immediately.

How to make it return output on first `arr[1].gets`?

PS. When I remove `loop { }` from server it works perfectly.

Comment: `loop { }` creates infinite loop..

Comment: @OMG since it is in separate thread, it should not affect (puts already wrote to stdout...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to to either [flush](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-flush) your output buffer:

```
puts 'Server started'
$stdout.flush
```

Or enable [sync](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) mode:

```
$stdout.sync = true
puts 'Server started'  # flushed automatically
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan! I would also appriciate some reading for better understand OS (and Ruby) IO, do you have some?

Comment: and why the second `gets` was working? does `gets` do flush internally?

Comment: And why it does not flush automatically?

Comment: `sync` is enabled only if the IO is associated with a terminal device.

Comment: It's not limited to a terminal device. [Sync](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) works with IO devices, including files. A terminal is a type of IO device: `$stdout.class
=> IO` and, when not redirected, `$stdout.tty?
=> true`.